# server error after deploying mvc app to aws

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, iis

I have an asp.net MVC application which allows a user to upload PDFs onto the system (the PDF files get saved into a folder called Surveys). The PDFs then get sent onto the Azure Read API and the data returned is stored in a .text file on the system (so I can later enter some of the data into a database).

This works fine when I test locally using IIS Express; I can upload a PDF and a .text file is made with the returned text. The problem is when I deploy the web app (to aws elastic beanstalk in this case), I get a server error when I upload a PDF:

> Server Error in '/BookingSystem_deploy' Application.
>   Could not find a part of the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Surveys\aaf6d80a-230f-4583-b57a-bf44ef49b903.pdf'.

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            string filename = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            string filepath = @"C:\Users\35385\source\repos\BookingSystem\BookingSystem\Surveys\" + filename;
            file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Surveys"), filename));
            await AzureVisionAPI.ExtractToTextFile(filepath);


            return View();
        }
```

I am guessing that the 'string filepath' needs to be changed in some way to support the directory change after deployment? Can anybody tell me what I need to do in this regard? Or if the error is something totally different that I am missing

edit: I have made some changes after doing some more research about my problem

changes to controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            string filename = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            string filepath = Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/Surveys/", filename));
            file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/Surveys/", filename)));
            await AzureVisionAPI.ExtractToTextFile(filepath);


            return View();
        }
```

Now I am receiving a different server error(although this one sounds like the path is now correct even though permission is denied):

> Server Error in '/BookingSystem_deploy' Application.
>   Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\BookingSystem_deploy\Surveys\70c1528a-49ce-4ec2-814e-df83b150224e.pdf' is denied.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Make sure enabled anonymous authentication in iis for your site.

2)your application pool identity is set as shown below:

[image]

set iis_iusrs, iusr permission to the site folder.

if application pool identity with not work then try to set the local system or network service.

to assign permission to the folder:

Right Click site Folder

Go to Security Tab

Click on Edit

Click on Add

Click on Advance

Find Now

Give Permission to IIS_IUSRS (Full Control)

Click On OK

Click On OK

Click On Full Control to allow

Click On OK

Again Run the Application

after assigning permission refresh site in iis.